# MongoDB with PHP : Bulk.upsert() insertion with PHP function Execute

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to use this MongoDB query from a PHP script :

```
Bulk.find(<query>).upsert().update(<update>);
```

Doc from the MongoDB operation :
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.upsert/#Bulk.find.update

Doc from the PHP execute operation :
http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.execute.php (see Example #3 Scope example)

I'm trying tu use the example no. 3 from the PHP doc to do a Bulk operation for my app.

But an equivalent code doesnt work.

The JS function I pass to MongoDB for the upsert operations thrue a PHP MongoCode Object: (http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongocode.php)

```
$function="function(idClient,name){
        bulk.find({idc:idClient,pid:partnerId}).upsert().update(
    {
           \$setOnInsert: {idc:idClient,pid:partnerId,dateCreate:new Date()},
           \$set: {name:name,n:0},
    });}";

$function=new \MongoCode($function,array('partnerId'=>$partnerId));
```

**The 3 variants I testet :**

**With var variant :**

```
// 1
$db->execute(new \MongoCode('var bulk = db.MyCollection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();'));    

while ([...])
{
    [...]   
    // 2
    $db->execute($function,array($idClient,$name));
}

// 3
$db->execute(new \MongoCode('bulk.execute();'));
```

1 returns : "exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token var"

2 returns : "exception: ReferenceError: bulk is not defined"

3 returns : "exception: ReferenceError: bulk is not defined"

**Without var variant :**

```
// 1
$db->execute(new \MongoCode('var bulk = db.MyCollection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();'));    

while ([...])
{
    [...]   
    // 2
    $db->execute($function,array($idClient,$name));
}

// 3
$db->execute(new \MongoCode('bulk.execute();'));
```

1 returns : array([...],"OK"=>1)

2 in first occurence returns : array([...],"OK"=>1)

2 in second occurence returns : "exception: ReferenceError: bulk is not defined"

3 returns : "exception: ReferenceError: bulk is not defined"

**Without var variant without while:**

```
// 1
$db->execute(new \MongoCode('var bulk = db.MyCollection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();'));    

//2
$db->execute($function,array($idClient,$name));


// 3
$db->execute(new \MongoCode('bulk.execute();'));
```

1 returns : array([...],"OK"=>1)

2 returns : array([...],"OK"=>1)

3 returns : array([...],"OK"=>1)

The 3rd variant works but, I want to upsert 240 000 documents, and I normaly don't have to create a new UnorderedBulkOp() for each upsert.

I'm Using MongoDB 2.6.7 with PHP 2.6.4.

Does somebody know how I can do ?

Thnak you

Comment: In shell modus, same operations are working.

Comment: because each mongocode instance is in its own instance - they do now know about each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a duplicate of your question in [PHP-1393](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-1393), which was opened on the PHP driver project. I'll repeat by original reply for the benefit of anyone else that comes across this question.

---

The [`eval`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/) command, which `MongoDB::execute()` invokes, does not share context between multiple invocations. If you're going to use server-side JavaScript evaluation, you'll need to pass in your entire script as a MongoCode object and invoke the command once.

That said, you are much better off just using [MongoUpdateBatch](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoupdatebatch.php) and the [`add()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mongowritebatch.add.php) method here, since all of your operations are updates. Using the driver to prepare and execute the write commands will be far more efficient that relying on server-side JavaScript.

As an example, we could use the driver's batch API to upsert 100 documents like so:

```
$batch = new MongoUpdateBatch($collection, ['ordered' => false]);

for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $batch->add([
        'q' => [ 'idc' => $i ],
        'u' => [
            '$setOnInsert' => [ 'idc' => $i ],
            '$set' => [ 'name' => 'Test' ],
        ],
        'upsert' => true,
    ]);
}

$batch->execute();
```

Note: the 1.x PHP driver does not provide the API you find in the MongoDB shell, which allows you to mix insert, update, and delete operations in the same batch. [MongoWriteBatch](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongowritebatch.php) (and its sub-classes) allow you to construct operation-specific batches, and have the driver handle splitting them into an optimal number of write commands.

Going forward, the `initializeUnorderedBulkOp()` and `initializeOrderedBulkOp()` API you find in the shell (and some other drivers) will ultimately be superseded by our recently published [CRUD API specification](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/crud/crud.rst). The CRUD API spec defines a much more concise interface for issuing bulk operations without *requiring* a fluent API (see the `bulkWrite()` method). You can expect to see that in the next major version of the PHP driver.